# What is Adhyatma (spiritual)?

Tags: terminology, spirituality

I am looking for a precise scriptural definition of **Adhyatma (अध्यात्म)** which is also known as **spiritual** in English.

So, Let me ask relevant questions:

- What is the definition (meaning) of Adhyatma?
- Is there any scriptural definition of Adhyatma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adhyatma means relating to [Atman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80tman_(Hinduism)) or belonging to self. In other words, transcendental.

The Sanskrit word अध्यात्म is combination of two words : **अधि + आत्म = अध्यात्म**.

Adhi(अधि) means over/upon/concerning and Aatm(आत्म) means the self/soul;
Adhyatma can be defined as : **आत्मनि अधि इति अध्यात्म ।**

From [Swadhyay](http://www.swadhyay.org/revolution/SpiritualRevolution.htm):

> ....the Sanskrit scriptures have a very precise definition of the word spirituality (adhyatma): **"aatmani adhi iti adhyatma"**, meaning all that which is performed in accordance with the wishes of the soul (aatma)is spirituality.

From Bhagavad Gita, 8.3 : अक्षरं ब्रह्म **परमं स्वभावोऽध्यात्ममुच्यते** । means:

> The indestructible, transcendental living entity is called Brahman, and **his eternal nature is called adhyātma, the self**.

---

The word "Spiritual" means about "concerning the spirit".

Comment: In which scripture, I can find "aatmani adhi iti adhyatma" ?

Comment: There is no "Soul"in our scripture. Atma and Soul are NOT synonymous. Soul has a begining and and an end. It does not pervade and is confined to a body. Animals do not have souls. There is no English term for Atma. Just use the Sanskrit word Atma please.

Comment: @RamaKrishnan I've also provided Sanskrit term आत्म with transliteration Aatma.

Comment: So which means Brahman's swaroopa is the Adhyatma which resides in the body of a human right? Adhyatma in Samkhya called Purusha? Right?

Answer (score 4):

**AdhyAtma is indwelling in the self or our own nature which is also called as svabhAv**. From Bhagvat Geeta Chapter 8.3.

> The Brahman is the highest indestructible, **AdhyAtman is explained to be the continuous flow of consciousness (svabhAva)**. Action is the name given to the creative force (visarga) that brings the variety of beings into existence.

Now, AchArya Abhinavgupta comments on this verse in this way-

> ...The word svabhAva is the state of being (bhAva) which never ceases (sva) and is expressed by the word consciousness. Therefore the word svabhAva means `continuous flow of consciousness`.

The translation which I have, which I find appealing, merge svabhAv & adhyAtma to denote non duality in our own being & the Brahman. Because in 7.29 AdhyAtma is said to be Brahman as well & this translation & commentary adjoining these two words - svabhAva & adhyAma as the continuous outflow of consciousness. Continuous outflow of consciousness is nothing but indwelling in our own real nature, considering ourselves distinct from the body & mind.

> Those who strive for release from old age and death, taking refuge in Me, they fully know the Brahman, **the highest self (AdhyAtma)** and all about action. 7.29

Note that - the verse numbers might be different  because the BG I have, has more verses & some different sanskrit verses.