# How to become spiritual?

Tags: spiritual-level, spirituality

I'm trying to become spiritual in the way of Hinduism. But I don't know how to start. 
I have few questions:

1. What scriptures to read that focus on spirituality?
2. What is the definition of spirituality in Hinduism?
3. How to become spiritual according to Hinduism?

Comment: Here is very similar question  enquiring about defination of spirituality https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11531/what-is-adhyatma-spiritual

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: The earlier question was on the definition of Adhyatma (अध्यात्म). Here the OP is asking about scriptures to be read, and definition of spirituality and how to become spiritual.

Comment: Yes :-)........

Comment: You are asking about a field, which is ABSTRACT in nature.  Scriptures can be quoted , but it is a complex subject.  Further, the definition for the entire humanity of SPIRITUALITY will be the same, and no separate definition in HINDUISM.  @Somanna

Comment: Do not try to become spiritual as your real nature is Atma. Just remove the screens/obstacles which prevents you from realisation of Atma. Enough!

Comment: For that understand your character you lived till . your behavior.....how many of your words hurt even 1% others. List down these. See how many you hurt, and also how you hurt your body and mind. What kind of decisions in your life hurt your body and sufferings. When I say hurt your body means, not falling down and hurt. Your life decisions and your characters together gave you illness of body and you lost your peace of mind because of it....think over it.... I can give you methods only. Where you stand I dont know because no face to face contact. Think and correct it!!! 1st step!

Comment: Ahimsa is Param Dharma as Bhagavad Gita says. Added to it, Satya, work without vengance, sacrifice, peace of mind, feeling for other jivas, not being attracted to too much comfortness and sensual attractions, tejas, forgiveness, braveness, purity of mind and body, dropping ahamkara, knowing Dharma and working as per Dharma, (Dharma is knowing the purpose of life and orienting actions towards it) are all qualities of a human that helps him and her becoming pure and all these are regarded as qualities of sat.

Comment: How would you define spirituality?

Answer (score 3):

- Just try to understand truth, it can be done anytime, and no matter what you are doing.
- Whenever you notice something, dont ignore, try to question it. try to understand it with logic and senses.
- By doing like this you will realise that reality is different than our mindset.
- Best source is Shreemad Bhagwadgeeta, it answers everything.
- You need not be a saint, you can read it in your current daily life and gain knowledge which is very useful in countering daily life problems and spiritual growth.
- Keep your social media sources also accordingly which will provide you daily insight.
- BK Shivani has very good knowledge, you can follow her.
- Remember, try to understand sources with sense and logic.

Comment: I agree, keep things short n simple, not to complicate it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

The questions asked are:

> 1. What scriptures to read that focuses on spirituality?
> 2. What is the definition of spirituality in Hinduism?
> 3. How to become spiritual according to Hinduism?

---

As the questions are related to Hinduism, the order of the questions, in my opinion,  are to be re-arranged as follows:

> 1. What is the definition of spirituality in Hinduism?
> 2. What scriptures to read that focuses on spirituality?
> 3. How to become spiritual according to Hinduism?

---

**1. Definition of spirituality in Hinduism**

The dictionary meaning of SPIRITUALITY is ***the quality that involves deep feelings and beliefs of a religious nature, rather than the physical parts of life.***

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spirituality

This definition applies to all human beings, irrespective of the religion/way of living they are following.  Hence, there will be **no separate definition** of SPIRITUALITY for the persons following Hinduism.

---

**Vaishnavism, Shaivism, Saakteism,** etc, are religions, being practiced by people under the name of Hinduism aka Sanaatana Dharma.

**Buddhism, Jainism, Christianity, Islam,** etc, are Religions.

All religions are insisting of prayers to God at certain intervals, reading of respective Holy text, following respective customs.

**Religion and SPIRITUALITY are different**.

---

The purpose of any religion is to show direction towards spirituality.   **We have to understand that spirituality has no affiliation to any religion.**

The spiritual practices make a human being realise, not understand, the God within oneself.

---

**2.  Scriptures to read that focuses on spirituality**

The core values of SPIRITUALITY advocate **self enquiry**.

Vedas, which are stated to be oldest and divine, advocated **self enquiry** for realising the TRUTH.

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2rvQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT239&lpg=PT239&dq=self+inquiry+in+vedas&source=bl&ots=ruAnKLJIgK&sig=ACfU3U1GwHa1W2MDu92a3HXorHKkshO08Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFpvuny_fiAhXNfX0KHVROBgE4ChDoATANegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=self%20inquiry%20in%20vedas&f=false

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neti_neti

---

If you are well versed in Sanskrit, you can go through Vedas, which contain pure SPIRITUAL aspects, Upanishads, etc.

You can go through the **Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi**, which will give you an idea about SELF ENQUIRY.

[https://www.amazon.com/Talks-Ramana-Maharshi-Munagala-Venkataramiah/dp/8188018074](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8188018074)

And, many other schools published their own literature on **SELF enquiry.**

---

**3. How to become spiritual?**

It is a complicated subject.  It depends on so many factors.

***For Example;***

You are running a manufacturing company, which is running successfully.  After some time, you got vexed with business, and want to close down your company.

Is it possible overnight?  No.

**Either you should get a buyer to sell it off as is where is basis, or you should start slowing down your business activities, and finally wind up the company.**

**You have to reduce your liabilities and sell off assets slowly, while reducing the raw material usage in manufacturing slowly.  It takes time, but surely can be done.**

---

When you embark upon SPIRITUALITY, you cannot overnight renounce the world, as Gautama, the Buddha did.  It is not possible in every case.

You have to reduce your desires slowly, discharge your responsibilities fully, engage yourself in SELF ENQUIRY or meditation regularly.

Sri Krishna said in B.G.

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते।
>
> सङ्गात् संजायते कामः कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते।।2.62।।
>
> In a person, meditating on sense-objects, attachment or them is born in succession; from attachment springs passion; from passion arises wrath.
>
> क्रोधाद्भवति संमोहः संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः।
>
> स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति।।2.63।।
>
> From wrath delusion comes to be; from delusion is the loss of memory; from the loss of memory is the loss of capacity to decide; due to the loss of capacity to decide, he perishes outright.

---

So it is the desire, whichever form it might be, that spurs an activity in the individual.

Desire can be towards copulation with opposite sex, towards acquiring riches, acquiring fame, etc.

It does not mean that desire is bad in toto, but excessive indulgence in the desires is bad.

It is but NATURAL to have an inclination towards copulation with opposite sex, but over indulgence will make a person weak physically and distract mentally one from SPIRITUALITY.

Acquiring riches for discharging one's responsibilities is good, but avarice should be avoided.

---

Final word:

Any SPIRITUAL practice without an assistance from a Guru in physical form or the invisible God, will not allow one to reach one's goal.

A Guru will teach, warn, guide at an appropriate time and give push, at an appropriate moment, to the disciple towards SELF enquiry.  Without the assistance of a Guru, one cannot understand whether one is progressing SPIRITUALLY or not.

For example:

People will be performing journey in Aeroplane.  The passengers do not know the height at which the Aeroplane is flying, how much time will it take to reach the distance, etc.

Only a pilot can tell this, but he is placed in a separate cabin, and will communicate with the passengers at an appropriate time.

SPIRITUAL journey is like flying in a Aeroplane.  Guru is like a pilot.

One has to wait for the guidance of the Guru.

Comment: Well thing is we can board a plane anytime we want, at will; when we need to go from one place to another, but in case of a guru, we don't know where to start, where to search and so many other related questions.

Comment: @Just_Do_It: Do you think everyone can afford to board a plane?  Out of Crores of people, only a few lakh people may board planes.  Similar is the case with a Guru.  It is not an easy thing to approach a Guru, appointed for one by the God.  It takes lot of time and struggle to get one.:-)

Comment: I agree with what you said, but it is also said that when we are ready the guru will find us so is there any use of seeking a guru coz we are not competent enough in that sense.

Comment: I agree with you.   However, you have to remember that my example of plane and pilot applies only after boarding the plane.  That means after Meeting with the Guru occurs @Just_Do_It