# What can we do so that all of us can increase own spiritual progress?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

According to the Varnashrama of Shreemad Bhagwat Purana, we all know that this is Kaliyug, so what can we do so that all of us can increase own spiritual progress and remove bad obstacles of past births and present birth?

We want all ways and ideas that will help everyone to prosper.

Comment: Welcome to our site! You can remove that NOTE part from your question as that is not needed :)

Comment: "so what can we do so that all of us can progress?" Excell in your job/school and give everything you accumulate to the poor. Do not be materialistic and take control of your senses an educate this to other people.

Comment: @Rickross O.K.◉‿◉(θ‿θ)ʘ‿ʘ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to become spiritual?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/how-to-become-spiritual)

Comment: @Shashwat Do you know how to flag comments? In future, click on the flag icon to the left of the comment directly so mods can clean them up. Mods are not going to read each and every comment.

Comment: @sv. I thought we could only flag posts (I wasn't able to see the option to flag). But I have done now.

Comment: Best and esiest way is to read or hear Bhagwat kathaa. In kaliyuga, hearing bhagwat katha will even grant you moksha easily which is tough to attain even with years of penance in other yugas. The biggest proof of power of bhagwat katha we can see as an example of King Prikshit who got moksha in 7 days by hearing bhagwat kathaa.

Comment: @user 17854 OK as a comment ..  it is *Daanam* or parting with resources has often been prescribed as an antidote of all ills in Kali yuga. Acquisitions only multiply spiritual misery. 

Religious and social Vrathams / functions and festivals like periodic river pushkarams has been recommended as occasions to gifting away and sharing.It includes love,service, duty .. in short supports Dharma in  every context.

The matter has been stressed repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by **removal of ego/Ahamkaar i.e. "I am this or that"** one can become spiritual and for it there are only 2 main paths for spiritual progress, either Bhakti Marg of Prakriti(from Puranas), you call yourself to be servant of God and than live in world like Tulsidas, Kabirdas, Ramanujacharya etc., did or Gyana Marg of Purush(from Vedas), accept Sanyas/monkhood and in which you identify self to be infinite Brahman and do sense-restraint and call this world and your body to be a temporary dream and live for selfless work for the welfare of society like Swami Vivekananda, Ramana Maharshi, Shankaracharya etc., did.

[The Remedy of Kaliyuga](http://bhagavata.org/canto12/chapter3.html)

> (16) The honorable king [Parîkchit] said: 'By what means my Lord, do
>   the people living in Kali-yuga eradicate the faults accumulating
>   because of that age? Please explain to me how it is. (17) How about
>   the yugas, the duties prescribed for them, the time they last and when
>   they end, as also the Time itself that represents the movement of the
>   Controller, of Lord Vishnu the Supreme Soul [see also time quotes
>   page].'
>
> (30) Sri Suka said: 'Kali-yuga is known as the age of ignorance, where
>   there is deceit, false testimony, sloth and lethargy, violence,
>   depression, lamentation, delusion, fear and poverty. (31) As a
>   consequence the mortals will be shortsighted, unfortunate, eating too
>   much, lusty and poverty-stricken while the women will act of their own
>   accord and be unchaste. (32) In the populated areas uncivilized people
>   will take high positions [and act like thieves], the Vedic scriptures
>   will be slighted by false doctrines [heretics], the political leaders
>   will devour the people and the twice-born souls will be dedicated to
>   their bellies and genitals. (33) The youngsters [the students] will be
>   averse to vows and impure in their engagements, the householders will
>   be beggars [with what they claim], the withdrawn souls [the
>   middle-aged, with no nature left to retreat into] will be
>   city-dwellers and the renounced order will greedily endeavor for
>   wealth [be engaged in 'reli-business']. (34) Smaller in size,
>   voracious and having many children, [the women will have] lost their
>   timidity and constantly speak harshly and with great audacity be as
>   deceitful as thieves. (35) The merchants will indulge in cheating so
>   that their business dealings will be wicked while the people
>   unnecessarily will consider any contemptible occupation [in the sex
>   industry or gambling business] a good job. (36) Servants will abandon
>   a master who lost his wealth - even if he is the best one around,
>   masters will abandon a handicapped servant - even when he belonged to
>   the family for generations, and cows will be abandoned [and killed] as
>   soon as they stopped giving milk. (37) Under the control of women, men
>   in Kali-yuga will be wretched and forsake their fathers, brothers,
>   friends and relatives, while regularly associating with their brothers
>   and sisters-in-law in a conception of friendship based upon sexual
>   enjoyment. (38) Laborers being dressed up as mendicants of austerity,
>   will accept religious charity to earn their living and mount a high
>   seat to speak about religious matters without any knowledge of dharmic
>   principles. (39-40) With their minds constantly full of stress,
>   emaciated by famine and taxes in times of scarcity with droughts on
>   the surface of the earth, oh King, the people of Kali-yuga will be
>   troubled by countless worries and live in fear. Lacking in clothing,
>   food, drink, rest, sexual love [vyavâya, also called 'change'],
>   bathing and personal ornaments they will appear like ghostly
>   creatures. (41) In the age of Kali one will even over a single coin
>   develop enmity [5.14 and 5.14: 26], reject friendly relations, kill
>   oneself [be suicidal] and even kill one's relatives [domestic
>   violence]. **(42) Only interested in the petty service of the stomach
>   and the genitals one, even being born in a respectable family, will
>   not protect the elderly parents, the wife and the children. (43) Oh
>   King, with their minds diverted by atheism the mortals in Kali-yuga in
>   general will not worship the Infallible One, the Personality of
>   Godhead who is the Supreme Spiritual Master of the three worlds at
>   whose feet the various masters bow down.** (44) In Kali-yuga the people
>   do not worship Him, even though He is the One by whom a person, who
>   dying in distress collapsing with a faltering voice helplessly chants
>   His name, is freed from the chains of karma and achieves the topmost
>   destination [see also B.G. 8: 10 and 6.2]. (45) The objects [and
>   food], places and the individual nature of man are as a result of
>   Kali-yuga all polluted [diseased, full of faults], but when one
>   installs Bhagavân, the Supreme Personality in one's heart, He takes
>   all this contamination away.
>
> (46) Of those human beings who but even heard, glorified, meditated,
>   worshiped or venerated the Supreme Lord, the inauspiciousness is
>   cleansed away that from a thousand births accumulated in their hearts.
>   (47) Just as the discoloration one finds in gold because of other
>   metals is removed by fire, the impurities of the mind of yoga
>   practitioners are removed when Lord Vishnu has entered their heart.
>   (48) Education, penance, breath control, friendship, bathing in holy
>   waters, vows, charity and praying with prayer beads do not realize as
>   full the purification of the mind as the presence of Him, the
>   Unlimited Personality of Godhead, in the heart. (49) Therefore oh
>   King, do your utmost best to establish Lord Kes'ava in your heart; the
>   moment you die [here after this week] you will with your attention
>   focussed on Him attain the highest destination. (50) The Supreme Lord
>   meditated upon by those who are dying is the Supreme Controller, the
>   Soul and Shelter of All, who leads them to their true identity my
>   dearest. (51) In the ocean of faults of Kali-yuga, oh King, there is
>   luckily one great good quality: just by singing about [and meditating
>   on] Krishna['s name, see bhajans] one can be liberated from material
>   bondage and achieve beatitude [see also bhâgavata dharma and kîrtana].
>   (52) The same result one achieves in Satya-yuga by meditating on
>   Vishnu, one achieves in Tretâ-yuga by worshiping with sacrifices and
>   one achieves in Dvâpara-yuga by serving the lotus feet [of Him in the
>   form of a king], is in Kali-yuga achieved by singing about [and
>   meditating on the names of] the Lord [see also 11.5: 38-40].'

Every man has an subtle memory of animal nature inherited from his past births that drags him back to sense gratification and slavery of matter, goal of spiritual person is to win over that nature. Once succeeded permanently, one has realized himself. Self is master of matter, not its slave.

[Swami Vivekananda](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Swami_Vivekananda)

> That man has reached immortality who is disturbed by nothing material
>   You have to grow from the inside out. **None can teach you, none can
>   make you spiritual. There is no other teacher but your own soul.**
>
> The goal of mankind is knowledge. . . . Now this knowledge is inherent
>   in man. No knowledge comes from outside: it is all inside. What we say
>   a man "knows," should, in strict psychological language, be what he
>   "discovers" or "unveils"; what man "learns" is really what he
>   discovers by taking the cover off his own soul, which is a mine of
>   infinite knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

As far as spiritual progress is concerned, we should not link it to any particular way of worship.  However, since the OP raised question based on the  Bhagavata Purana, I would like to provide answer based on that text only.

The Bhagavata (VII.  5.  18)  speaks  of  nine  aspects  of  bhakti  in  a well-known  verse.  They  are:

> 1. Hearing  the  names  of  God  or  His Incarnation  chanted  or  sung  by  others,  or  songs  in  praise  of,  or the   narration   of, His   charms,   pastimes   and   attributes.
> 2. Chanting or singing His names, narrating or singing His charms.
> 3. Remembering  or  thinking  of  His  names  and  charms.
> 4. Showing respect  to  Him  by  visiting  the  sacred  places  associated  with  His pastimes ,  looking  at  His  images or pictures depicting His pastimes, serving and keeping company with His devotees and showing respect to things connected with His memory
> 5. Worship  of  Him  in  images  by  offering  flowers,  sandal paste,  food,etc.
> 6. Bowing  down  before  Him  or  His  images  at  the  place  of worship.
> 7. Serving  Him  in  the  attitude  of  a  devoted  servant.
> 8. Comradeship  -  to  think  that  one  is  His  loving  and  intimate  friend and  He  too  is  such,  and  to  behave  towards  Him accordingly,generally  through  His  images.
> 9. Resignation  to  the  Lord  - devoting  oneself  entirely  to  His  services.  According  to  the devotional  schools  these  steps belong  scriptural devotion.
>
> http://estudantedavedanta.net/Nine_means.pdf

These acts definitely, increase own spiritual progress.

If the OP is interested in serious spiritual aspects, he/she can go through this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35470/3869) for having a better understanding of the subject

Answer (score 0):

Serving all beings is required for spiritual progress.

> I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
>   presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
>   If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
>   ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
>   ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
>   persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
>   upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
>   mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
>   Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
>   pleased with him for proffering such worship. A man should, however,
>   worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
>   include the love of all beings, until he actually realises My presence
>   in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centred and
>   makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
>   recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
>   subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
>   deprivation of self-interest). **So overcoming the separateness of a
>   self-centred life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honour and
>   love, recognising that such service is really being rendered to Me who
>   reside in all beings as their innermost soul**.

***Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27***